# React How to render a component twice with one api request

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, redux-toolkit

**There is a component:**

```
const Navbar = ({...props}) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const navigation = useSelector(state => state.navigation)
    const [nav] = navigation.navs.filter(nav => nav.slug === props.navGroup)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchNavigation());
    }, [dispatch])

    return (
        <nav className={styles.nav}>
            {nav
            ? nav.all_elements.map(link =>
                <Link 
                className={styles.navLink}
                to={link.url}
                key={link.id}
                >
                    {link.name}
                </Link>
            )
            : <div>Something else</div>
            }
        </nav>
    )
}
```

**Reducer**:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { fetchNavigation } from "../services/fetchNavigation"

const initialState = {
    "count": 0,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "navs": [],
    "loaded": false
}

const navSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'navigation',
    initialState: initialState,
    extraReducers: {
        [fetchNavigation.fulfilled]: (state = initialState, action) => {
            state.count = action.payload.count;
            state.next = action.payload.next;
            state.previous = action.payload.previous;
            state.loaded = true
            state.navs = action.payload.results;
        }
    },
})
```

**Async action**:

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { instance } from "../../API/config"

export const fetchNavigation = createAsyncThunk(
    "navigation/fetchNavigation", async () => {
        const response = await instance.get(`nav/`)
        return response.data
    }
);
```

**Problem**:

I show the component in the header and footer
therefore, it makes two requests to API, how can i check that the data is already in the store before calling createAsyncThunk?
I tried to get the current state of the 'loaded' key through getState() but it does not change InitialState before the request, so nothing came out

Comment: fetchNavigation is what fetches the content that you don't want to fetch twice, right? So then run fetchNavigation in the parent component instead, and then send the result as a prop to the NavBar component.

Comment: @EmilKarlsson How correct is this approach to use from an architectural point of view?

Comment: That depends. Do you expect that the data you fetch may change between renderings? If yes, then you can't just load it once and be done with it. If no, then you do indeed need to check if the data has been fetched before.